# Javascript game loads slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a puzzle game with javascript. I am grabbing an image for the puzzle from a url and loading it into the main div. But when I load the webpage it takes a second until everything loads correctly. How can I get this to look smoother?

Thanks

My webpage with the bug at start up:

http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~jamesber/GameOne.html#

My code:

```
 $(function (){

 var plant = "";

$.ajax({"url":"http://beta.botanicalapp.com/api/v1/plants/?photo=true"})
.success(function(fullData){
        plant = fullData[2].plant.image_default.url;

        $("#puzzle div").css({'background-image':'url('+ plant +')'});
        $("#helper").attr("src",plant);
        var puzzle = $("#puzzle");
        var pieces = $("#puzzle div");

            pieces.sort(function (a, b) {
                var temp = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
                var isOddOrEven = temp % 2;
                var isPosOrNeg = temp > 5 ? 1 : -1;
                return (isOddOrEven * isPosOrNeg);
            }).appendTo(puzzle);

        var timer;
        var secs = 0;
        var mins = 0;
        var millsecs = 0;
        var timeString = document.getElementById("time");
        timeString.innerHTML = "00:00:00";

        function update(){
            if(millsecs == 100) {
                secs++;
                millsecs = 0;
                if(secs == 60){
                    mins++;
                    secs = 0;
                }
            } 
            else {
                millsecs++;
            }
            if((millsecs<10) && (secs<10) && (mins<10)) {
        timeString.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':0' + secs + ':0' + millsecs;
            }
            else if ((millsecs<10) && (secs<10)) {
        timeString.innerHTML = mins + ':0' + secs + ':0' + millsecs;
            }
            else if ((millsecs<10) && (mins<10)) {
        timeString.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':' + secs + ':0' + millsecs;
            }
            else if((secs<10) && (mins<10)){
        timeString.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':0' + secs + ':' + millsecs;
            } 
            else if (millsecs<10) {
            timeString.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs + ':0' + millsecs;
            }
            else if (secs<10){
            timeString.innerHTML = mins + ':0' + secs + ':' + millsecs;
            } 
            else if (mins<10) {
        timeString.innerHTML = '0' + mins + ':' + secs + ':' + millsecs;
            } 
            else {
            timeString.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs + ':' + millsecs;
            }   
        }

        function start(){
            timer = setInterval(function() {update()}, 10);
        }

        start();    
        initSwap();

        function initSwap() {
            initDroppable($("#puzzle div"));
            initDraggable($("#puzzle div"));
        }


        function initDraggable($elements) {
            $elements.draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                revert: "invalid"
            });
        }

        $("#final").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            resizable: false,
            height: 520,
            position: [250,75],
            dialogClass: "fixed-dialog",
            draggable: false
        });

        function initDroppable($elements) {
            $elements.droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                over: function (event, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var linew1 = $(this).after(ui.draggable.clone());
                    var linew2 = $(ui.draggable).after($(this).clone());
                    $(ui.draggable).remove();
                    $(this).remove();
                    initSwap();
                    var finished = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
                    var started = '';
                    $("#puzzle div").each(function(){
                        var image = $(this).attr("id");
                started += image.replace("recordArr_","")+",";
                        });
                started = started.substr(0(started.length)-1);
                        if(started == finished){
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                    $("#thePlant").attr("src",plant);
                            $("#final").dialog("open");
                        }
                }
            });
        }
});
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is happening in the `success` / `done` callback of the Ajax call.

Even if the image is cached or anything like that, you still have the overhead of:

- make HTTP connection
- request resource
- receive response
- close connection

That's why there's a lag at startup.

You should start that Ajax call and handle the response with the image separately from rendering the rest of the page.

*p.s.*
You should switch `.success` to `.done`, because jQuery's new(er) Deferred objects prefer it, and the old methods are [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: I tried that but when I call the Ajax separately it doesn't load the image because I'm thinking it takes too long by the time the rest of the page loads. I updated my webpage if you wanna see what I mean.

Comment: You need to wait to start the game until the photo has loaded: render the page, get everything set up, but call a function like `startGame` when the picture has loaded. `startGame` would fill in the right image and start the timer.  While you're waiting, it's probably a good idea to have a spinner or something saying "Hey, loading, wait a second"

Comment: Yeh. Sorry I'm very new to javascript. Is there like a sleep function I can use or something to stall the rest of the code? Or do I need to pull that code out of the function() call?